# Summation of $\int\frac{1}{1+x}dx$ in a range of 1 to infinity.

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

Let $0 < \alpha < \beta < 1$. Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{1/(k+\beta)}^{1/(k+\alpha)} \frac{1}{1+x}dx$$

is equal to

$$
\begin{align}
&(A)\ln \frac{\beta}{\alpha}\qquad\qquad (B)\ln\frac{1+\beta}{1+\alpha} \\
&(C)\ln\frac{1+ \alpha}{1+ \beta}\qquad\ (D)\infty
\end{align}
$$

Please tell me the approach.

Comment: What is it supposed to be equal to? It is easy to show it converges, but not obvious what it converges to.

Comment: there are 4 options 
(A) loge β/α
(B) loge (1+β)/(1+α)
(C) loge (1+ α)/(1+ β)
(D) ∞.

Comment: So with a little numerical experimentation, it looks like (B), but I cannot see why at the moment!

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{k+\beta}}^{\frac{1}{k+\alpha}} \frac{1}{1+x}\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{\frac{1}{k+\beta}+1}^{\frac{1}{k+\alpha}+1} \frac{1}{t}\ \mathrm dt$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\log\left(\frac{1}{k+\alpha}+1\right)-\log\left(\frac{1}{k+\beta}+1\right)\right]$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\left(\frac{(k+\beta)(k+\alpha+1)}{(k+\alpha)(k+\beta+1)}\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{\alpha!(n+\beta)!(\beta+1)!(n+\alpha+1)!}{\beta!(n+\alpha)!(\alpha+1)!(n+\beta+1)!}\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{(\beta+1)(n+\alpha+1)}{(\alpha+1)(n+\beta+1)}\right)$$
$$=\log\left(\frac{\beta+1}{\alpha+1}\right)$$

Comment: Or another way: The sum in the fourth line is telescoping.